# Ng serve works in Windows but fails in Ubuntu

Tags: angular, ubuntu, compilation

I have tried and read all issues about this problem but I couldn't solve it. 
My angular 4 program compiles successfully in windows but there are errors serving it in Ubuntu. And ng build --prob doesn't work on Ubuntu or Windows. This is a screenshot of the error I get when compiling. Can anyone help?
 [image: This is a screenshot of the error I get when compiling]

Comment: did you run ```npm i``` command?

Comment: I noticed you wrote `ng build --prob `. Have you tried `ng build --prod `

Comment: Bear in mind that file paths in Linux are case sensitive, so if the directory is actually called `payment` not `Payment` for example, Linux will not find it.

Comment: strangely enough, after all that struggling and trying practically everything, the problem was just the fact that Ubuntu is case sensitive and Windows is not, and I corrected the upper case and lower case in all directories and addresses and it compiled!

Answer (score 1):

As I can see the issue is not in compilation -- but in finding the files that are mentioned and to be fetched.

Ubuntu (Linux) and Windows have different sets of instructions and ways of traversing the file.

For Example: in Windows in cmd window **cd c:** will work, in Ubuntu **c:/** works.

My suggestion is **make new project in Ubuntu** and kindly understand how the files are being fetched and *'URL' correction needs to be done in individual files* (though this is also strange).

Your project is running properly in windows and opening without errors (if it really is) -- shows there is nothing wrong with your Angular-Code, npm, angular-cli pakcage or NodeJs.

Just, for precaution -- delete Node, NPM and Angular-CLI and remove them from ubuntu and take a **fresh install of all 3 -- NodeJS, NPM, Angular-CLI**. Sometimes, some strange errors happen due to versions of Node and NPM not up-to-date. (And, you are now compiling your project on new computer -- means the versions of Node/NPM/Angular-CLI might not be the same as in your previous windows computer). So, why take risk. Just remove from new system and re-install these 3 dependencies ... and ping back ... what happens!

Answer (score 1):

Just rename GIT with git and it should work, Linux make the difference between Uppercase and Lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, you are in the proper directory where your project is while doing ngServe.
Also make sure you have injected all the component in app.module.ts with proper path.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the imports are correct in the below listed files:

```
app.module.ts
payment.service.ts
app-routing.module.ts
```

Example:
Say I have a js file and two child directories under a root directory as shown below.

```
server.js
model/user.js
routes/api/home.js
routes/api/user.js
```

If I need to import `user.js` in the `model` directory into `server.js`, I will use path: `./model/user`.
Note: Here the `model` directory is in the same directory as `server.js`.

If I need to import `user.js` in the `model` directory into `routes/api/user.js`, I will use path: `../../model/user`.

In your case, update the path based on where the files are stored. That should solve the problem.